# Do I have to reinstall XQuartz every time I upgrade MacOS?

Tags: macos, xquartz

I use a slightly weird setup where I will connect from my Mac laptop to a linux machine, using `ssh -X`, and from there connect to a Windows machine using `rdesktop`. This works just fine, but whenever I update Mac OS (even minor upgrades), I find I have to re-install XQuartz. If I don't, `rdesktop` fails with the message `ERROR: Failed to open display:`. After I re-install XQuartz, it works as expected (no reboot or log out or anything, just opening a new connection with `ssh -X`).

Is there a way I can avoid having to reinstall XQuartz all the time? It gets a little annoying.

Comment: It happens to me as well. Evertytime I update macOS Sierra I have to reinstall XQuartz. Have you reinstalled yours yet? In case no, it might be worthwhile reporting a bug at their website. I plan to do that next time I updated my macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really - the tool is one that's very command line - run and bind against the specific OS that it's installed in.

I realize this may not be the answer you like, but I'm actually floored it keeps working as long as it has. Here's to hoping this is our main complaint on this tool.